# how to import some other scss files in the middle of main scss with @use and @forward

Tags: css, sass

I have style.scss (my main scss), _style2.scss, and style.css

```
// style.scss
body {
    background:red;
}
@import '_style2.scss';
div {
    background: blue;
}
```

When this is compiled to style.css it looks like exactly what i want it to look like:

```
// style.css
body {
  background: red;
} 
p {
  background: green;
}
div {
  background: blue;
}
```

Because @import will be eventually removed from Sass, now we should use @use and @forward, but I can't make it to work with @use and @forward because: **Error: @use rules must be written before any other rules.**
It only works when my @use is at the beginning of the file, but i want to import my _style2.scss in the middle, how to do it?

Comment: Just do it at the top. It won't affect the rest of your stylesheet. There are videos on the use of use and forward, as well as the use of using folders for different types of sass files

Comment: I know i can use it at the top. I was just curious if it is possible to make it work just like @import. Guess i will use mixins then.